# data.map is not a function typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
  list(): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.http.get('url').pipe(
      map((data: any[]) =>
        data.map((item: any) =>
          new Recipe({
            name: item.recipeName
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

I am getting an error saying "data.map is not a function" even though I clearly say that data is type of an array. If I do `Object.values(data)` it works fine. But why is data an Object? Shouldn't it be an Array? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can tell Typescript that the value is an array, but that doesn't mean that it's actually an array at run time. No idea what these APIs are and what value the callback gets passed, but since you get that error it's certainly not an array.

Comment: could be an error page instead of data being returned.

Comment: The array you are looking for is probably `data.data`

Comment: @FelixKling Aha thanks. I thought the rules applied at runtime too. The api just returns json data.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Hey. It says that "data does not exist on type Object". I will probably create another post regarding this.

Comment: @Diar: https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response